# Is there any way to initialize several variables from one array?

Tags: c#

In some languages it is possible to initialize several variables at the same time from an array.
For example in PHP you can do something like this:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
list($a, $b, $c) = $array;
```

Is it possible to do this in C# as well?

I want to apply this on a program where I read all lines from a file where I know every line is two words only (never more, never less). 
I know I can create the function myself (and sending in variables by reference with `out`keyword) but I would like to know if any built in functionality exists for it.

I would like to know this mostly for the reason that if it is possible the code might be more readable for other developers.

Comment: The answer is no, which is good as I would say it is far less readable than assigning the values manually

Comment: Tuple assignment is not available in C#, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299947/c-sharp-multi-assignment

Comment: I just realized that you don't need my answer. (I had initially understood "I know I can create the function myself..." differently.)

Answer (score 2):

In C#,

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
string s1 = arr1[0];
string s2 = arr1[1];
string s3 = arr1[2];
```

Comment: This is the way i am currently doing it. What i am looking for is a way to do it in one command, like Ispiro suggests but with some functinality in C# (if it exsists)

Answer (score 2):

If readability is the issue and if I understand you correctly - I don't know of an in-built way. But you can create a function for that.

```
void Doit(out string one, out string two, string[] input)
{
    one = input[0];
    two = input[1];
}
```

And use it thus:

```
string[] s = new string[] { "First", "Second" };
string a, b;
Doit(out a, out b, s);
```

I just realized that you don't need my answer. (I had initially understood "I know I can create the function myself..." differently.) Perhaps, though, it can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] array = new char[] {'a','b','c'};
```

Comment: I was not interested in initializing an array but several variables from values of an array, Ispiros answer is more they way I want it but I am wondering if it exists and built in way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no buit-in way to do that.

Maybe a good way to implement that functionality is by using extension methods in order to improve readability.

Simply write the needed code in a extension method that can be attached to the type you want to initialize like a list in your example above and take an array as input to that function:

```
public static class Extensions {

    public static void initFromArray<T> (this List<T> list, T[] array) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {

            list[i] = array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this method for example like in the following:

```
int[] array = new int [] { 1, 4, 6, 2, 5 };

List<int> list = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) list.Add(0);

list.initFromArray<T>(array);
```