# Possible to initialize multiple variables from a tuple?

Tags: c#, tuples

In some languages (such as PHP, Haskell, or Scala), you can assign multiple variables from tuples in a way that resembles the following pseudocode:

```
list(string value1, string value2) = tupleWithTwoValues;
```

I can't find a way to do this in C#, however, without writing longer, uglier code:

```
string firstValue = tupleWithTwoValues.Item1;
string secondValue = tupleWithTwoValues.Item2;
```

This two-line solution is obviously not the end of the world, but I'm always looking for ways to write prettier code.

Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Comment: You can't initialize multiple variables from tuple. And yes, tuples are ugly in C#

Comment: See also this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28261964/240733

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is now available in C# 7:

```
public (string first, string last) FullName()
{
    return ("Rince", "Wind");
}

(var first, var last) = FullName();
```

You can even use a single var declaration:

```
var (first, last) = FullName();
```

More on destructuring tuples in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#deconstruction).

Answer (score 7):

*Valid up to C# 6:*

No, this is not possible. There's no such language feature in C#.

If you think the following code:

```
string firstValue = tupleWithTwoValues.Item1;
string secondValue = tupleWithTwoValues.Item2;
```

is ugly, then you should reconsider using tuples at the first place.

---

*UPDATE: As of C# 7, tuple deconstruction is now possible. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#deconstruction) for more information.*

See Jared's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43076100/245183) as well.

Comment: I would add that "moving things around" is not something that you would do very frequently in C#. Unless you want to give the thing a shorter name, and use it many times in your code, you would probably access `tupleWithTwoValues.Item1` directly instead of putting it in a variable.

Comment: True. Just seconds after posting that, it hit me that a richer solution (like a DTO) is often the way to go whenever I'm considering a tuple.

Comment: @Micah Yes, including semantics is always a plus. Tuples are usually a good thing in very specific scenarios only.

Comment: This is now available in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#deconstruction

Comment: @Jared Thanks for pointing that out. Updated my answer, although back in 2014 that language feature hadn't existed.

Answer (score 3):

You can technically do this with a single statement, rather than two statements, using the following syntax, although the character count is almost identical.

```
string firstValue = tupleWithTwoValues.Item1
    , secondValue = tupleWithTwoValues.Item2;
```

Answer (score 1):

No this is not supported in C#, although others have suggested adding a feature like this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299947/c-sharp-multi-assignment) and [here](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Dec-23.html)).

It is supported by F#, however:

```
let (f, b) = ("foo", "bar")
```

Comment: It is now available in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#deconstruction

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible in C#.
You'll need to install the package Value.Tuple in your project.
You can do like this

```
List<Tuple<string,string>>() lstTuple = GetYourTupleValue();
foreach(var item in lstTuple)
{
  (string Value1, string Value2 ) = item;
}
Console.WriteLine(item.Value1);
```

Answer (score 0):

when it comes to lists, you can do something like this:

```
var list = new List<string>{tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2};
```

(It's not that wordy)
But for multiple variables, no. You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

```
public static TResult Select<T1, T2, TResult>(this Tuple<T1, T2> source, Func<T1, T2, TResult> selector)
{
    return selector(source.Item1, source.Item2);
}
// this allows us ...
GetAssociationAndMember().Select((associationId,memberId) => {
    // do things with the aptly named variables
});
```