# Tuple unrolling in C# similar to Python

Tags: c#, tuples

In Python we can unroll a tuple with similar syntax:

```
a, b = (1, 2)
```

Is there are similar structure in C#? Or accessing elements like:

```
Tuple<int, int> t = Tuple.Create(1, 2);
Console.Write(t.Item1);
```

the only possible way?

Comment: *Not related but swift also support that. ( Also ES6)

Comment: PS , the term is called _destructuring_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tuple destructuring (sometimes called "explosion"), i.e. distributing its elements over several variables, is not directly supported by the C# language.

You could write your own extension method(s):

```
static void ExplodeInto<TA,TB>(this Tuple<TA,TB> tuple, out TA a, out TB b)
{
    a = tuple.Item1;
    b = tuple.Item2;
}

var tuple = Tuple.Create(1, 2);
int a, b;
tuple.ExplodeInto(out a, out b);
```

The above example is just for pairs (i.e. tuples with two items). You would need to write one such extension method per `Tuple<>` size/type.

<strike>In the upcoming version of the C# language, you will likely be able to declare variables inside an expression. This might then possibly enable you to combine the last two lines of code above into `tuple.ExplodeInto(out int a, out int b);`.</strike>

> <sup>Correction: Declaration expressions have apparently been dropped from the planned features for C# 6, or at least restricted; as a result, what I suggested above would no longer work.</sup>

Comment: It will be problematic with  `(1,2...n)`

Comment: @RoyiNamir: `(1,2,...,n)` is not valid C# syntax. But if you mean by that a tuple of any length: You will need one extension method for each specific number of tuple items. That is, you need one extension method for `Tuple<A,B>`, one for `Tuple<A,B,C>`, one for `Tuple<A,B,C,D>`, etc. (That is the usual pattern in .NET. There are also several tuple types; or several `Action<>` and `Func<>` types.)

Comment: Of course it's not a valid syntax. I was referring to a variable length :-)

Comment: *It will be problematic with (1,2...n)* `Tuple` only goes so high https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx