# A method returns a tuple, how to assign two variables that take the result of the tuple in C#

Tags: c#, tuples

I am new to the concept of `Tuples`.

I have a `Value Tuple` method that returns two things - a `certificate` used for digital signature and an `enum` which is a result(with values "success" and "cannotsigndoc").

I want to collect the result of this method in two variables.

Here is the method:

```
    public (InvoiceResult resultValue, X509Certificate2 cert) GetDefaultCertificateStoredOnTheCard()
    {
        var resultValue = InvoiceResult.Success;
        X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, true);

        // by thumbprint, there is only one
        certs = certs.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "6BB4AZD483206Z44B992799541114536579CF2B3", true);

        if (certs.Count == 0)
        {
            resultValue = InvoiceResult.CannotFindSignature;
            throw new ArgumentException("Please insert smart card to obtain certificate.");
        }
        X509Certificate2 cert = certs[0];

        RSACryptoServiceProvider key;

        if (cert.HasPrivateKey)
        {
            // software cert
            key = cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

        }
        else
        {
            // certificate from smartcard
            CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(1, "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider");
            csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;
            key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
        }

        return (resultValue, cert);
    }
```

And here is where I want to collect the results of the method in two variables:

```
var certificate,resultValue = GetDefaultCertificateStoredOnTheCard();
```

These are the  errors I get from the following:

> "Implicitly-typed variables cannot have multiple declarators"
>
> "Implicitly-typed variables must be initialized"

Comment: You're missing parentheses around the deconstructed variable names `var (certificate, resultValue) = GetDefaultCertificateStoredOnTheCard();`. See docs for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#deconstruction

Comment: Thank you for the swift response phuzi.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43076100/7556646

Comment: Cheers Wollmich, the question has already been answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line where you assign the variables by adding parenthesis:

```
var (certificate, resultValue) = GetDefaultCertificateStoredOnTheCard();
```

This resource may be helpful:

https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/17/c-sharp-7-preview-using-tuples-to-return-multiple-values